# Intellij search other project from current project

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to put my coding notes in a single project 'Notes' in markdown files.  Is it possible to search the files in the 'Notes' project whilst working on another project in Intellij/Pycharm ?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you want to do. E.g. Define "search". Do you mean to perform an IDE search? Or do you just want to view the contents of the files and do `Ctrl+F` on them?

Comment: Be able to search the contents of the files and then easily go to possible match.  eg (I'm not clear what you mean by IDE search though - identify object usages? - no not looking for that) . Sorry for not being clear the first time.